# Pass data from a controler loading a second view [codeigniter]

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, foreach, view

I have a question about the usage of $data to pass information from a controller to a view.

For example I'm using this format to fill a select

```
$data['array_name'] = model_name->model_method();

$this->load->view('main_view',$data);
```

Everything is ok, then I'm using Ajax to load information on select change:

1. Information is send from the view to the controller
2. The controller load a model and get an array of information from it
3. I use foreach to store every record in data['name']
4. I load a second view that only containt the following code

**ajax_function()**

```
$data['name'] = contacts_model->get_contacts($post_value);

$this->load->view('contacts',$data);
```

**second view**

```
<?php
foreach ($name as $n)
  {
    echo $n;
  } 

?>
```

and I'm getting this error message, I check if the array was empty but is not....
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I'm guessing if it's because previous I use $data to load information on the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `$name` as in foreach its best practice to check it is array or not,
you can use is_array() ,

```
if(is_array($name)) {
    foreach ($name as $n) {
     echo $n;
    }     
}
```